# Get Discount from Global Discount in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I've been stuck here for almost 4 hours. There is Global Discount in my invoice_header table. And I wanna count discount for every items in my invoice_detail proportion from value in invoice_detail and in the end and grouping by item_code.

The problem is I can't sum value in invoice_detail :

invoice_header : `id, global_discount`

invoice_detail : `id, invoice_header_id, stock_code, value`

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN A.global_discount <> 0  
                THEN ((B.value * A.global_discount /
                    (SELECT SUM(value) FROM invoice_detail WHERE invoice_header_id = A.id)
                    )) 
                ELSE 0 
                END)/1.1
            AS DISCOUNT
        FROM invoice_header A 
            JOIN invoice_detail B
        ON A.id = B.invoice_header_id
        GROUP BY stock_code
```

I got error like this :

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

I've cut some code. The formula is `Discount = value * global_discount / sum(value)`

Comment: Please add sample tables @Colour Dalnet

Comment: @SarathAvanavu : Sample Table is above the code.

Comment: That is not sample table. That is **Sample code**. How can we know the structure of table and how data is scattered.

Comment: @SarathAvanavu : I'm sorry, I just make a sample problem from my 53 fields in my real table into sample table. You just need create that 2 fields in invoice_header and that 4 fields in invoice_details. I just want to know the logic from this query. If you can produce same result even with different logic its ok. Do you mean "script for creating sample database and table for this case"?

Comment: Thats ok. No problem. @Colour Dalnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `Sum` and make the query as `Sub-select` and do the Sum in `outer Query`.

Also you don't need `Case` part, when `A.global_discount` is `0` then `Discount` will be `0`. Try this.

```
SELECT Sum(INT_DISCOUNT) / 1.1 AS Discount,stock_code
FROM   (SELECT stock_code,B.value * A.global_discount / (SELECT Sum(value)
                                              FROM   invoice_detail
                                              WHERE  invoice_header_id = A.id) INT_DISCOUNT
        FROM   invoice_header A
               JOIN invoice_detail B
                 ON A.id = B.invoice_header_id
        ) A 
 Group by stock_code
```

Comment: Hello there, I've modify `SELECT Sum(DISCOUNT)` into `SELECT Sum(INT_DISCOUNT)`. But still got error like this : `Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Column 'invoice_header.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'invoice_detail.value' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2`

Comment: @ColourDalnet - check now.

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to make grouping outside sub-select right? This is working good in my sample table. Once again, thank you very much.

Comment: Owh ya, is it really no problem to remove `CASE WHEN A.global_discount <> 0` ? I think `SELECT Sum(value) FROM   invoice_detail WHERE  invoice_header_id = A.id` is executed in every rows. There are just about 10% from total rows which have `global_discount > 0`

Comment: @ColourDalnet - yeah now it will be executed for each row better keep it sorry for misguiding .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE AS
(        
    SELECT B.*,A.global_discount,SUM(B.value) OVER(PARTITION BY B.invoice_header_id) SUMM
    FROM invoice_header A 
    JOIN invoice_detail B
    ON A.id = B.invoice_header_id
)
SELECT stock_code,SUM(CASE WHEN global_discount = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (VALUE * global_discount)/SUMM END)/1.1 SUMMMM
FROM CTE
GROUP BY stock_code
```